# finishTransaction for each SKPaymentQueue?

Tags: ios, swift, storekit

[Documentation for `SKPaymentQueue`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/storekit/skpaymentqueue) notes:

> To process a payment, first attach at least one observer object to the
>   queue.

I have two observers one in the `AppDelegate` (for provisioning content), and one in a `UIViewController` (for updating UI state based on payment progress).

The documentation then says:

> Your observer should process the transaction and then remove it from
>   the queue.

Does this mean I can call `SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)` in both observers (the `AppDelegate` and `UIViewController`) like this:

```
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction in transactions {
        switch transaction.transactionState {
        case .deferred:
            print("deferred")
        case .purchasing:
            print("purchasing")
        case .purchased:
            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
        case .failed:
            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
        case .restored:
            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
        }
    }
}
```

I thought `SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)` destroys the transaction event for all listeners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some experimentation doing something similar recently, I found that multiple SKPaymentQueue observers work - they will all get called for each transaction.  However after finishTransaction() is called, no remaining observers will be called (as you guessed at in your question, and which also makes sense).

I also determined that the observers always seem to be called in the order you added them.  So if you want both observers to always get every transaction, make sure that the observer you add last is the only one that ever calls finishTransaction().

Answer (score 0):

When you display a `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` View Controller, you can re-order the observers so that the VC's methods are called prior to the App Delegate observer methods being called.

```
SKPaymentQueue.default().remove(AppDelegate.shared)
SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
SKPaymentQueue.default().add(AppDelegate.shared)
```

Or, I suppose, remove App Delegate observation entirely.